# XHR no javascript para Python exibe três vezes o retorno

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, xmlhttprequest, iis-7

Recentemente eu implantei Python no meu servidor IIS, e comecei a testar algumas requests. Primeiro eu criei o código de javascript, como você pode ver abaixo:

```
    sendRequest = function() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState = 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log("ok!");
                var response = this.responseText;
                console.log(response);
            }
        };
        http.open("GET", "test.py", true);
        http.send();
        console.log("called");
    }
```

O arquivo test.py tem o seguinte código:

```
 print('Content-Type: text/plain')
 print('')
 print('Hello!')
 print('Hi')
```

No entanto, o output que eu recebo no console é:
ok!
(nada)
ok!
Hello!
Hi
ok!
Hello!
Hi

Até onde eu testei, a função sendRequest só é executada uma vez, além do mais, descobri que a função   `onReadyStateChange` é executada três vezes, por quê?

Alguém poderia me dizer por que isso acontece? Qualquer ajuda é apreciada.

Comment: Pode ser no momento que você chama `sendRequest`, creio não ser problema nem no Ajax nem no Python. Poste o código de maneira que possamos reproduzir, o que executa o `sendRequest`? É um onclick?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não, é por meio do console do Chrome. Além do mais, eu coloquei avisos para mostrar quantas vezes o trecho foi repetido, de modo que me parece que a função onReadyStateChange é chamada 3 vezes

Comment: Com não, o console se repete por haver mais de uma chamada, o console é só um debug, a função onReadyStateChange é chamada 3 vezes porque provavelmente o evento está sendo chamado 3 vezes sendRequest

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então, você acha que é algo com o script python? Eu nunca vi um XHR que eu testei mudar de status 3 vezes. Vou tentar acompanhar no console as requisições

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez o problema seja o seu if que está errado:

```
if (this.readyState = 4
```

Quando o correto deveria ser:

```
if (this.readyState == 4
```

Assim:

```
sendRequest = function() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("ok!");
            var response = this.responseText;
            console.log(response);
        }
    };

    http.open("GET", "test.py", true);
    http.send();
    console.log("called");
};
```

Comment: Poxa que baita distração minha, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o problema esteja em seu if

```
if (this.readyState = 4 && this.status == 200) {
```

Você está atribuindo 4 para `this.readyState` e verificando se o status da conexão com 200.

Como o estado da conexão muda durante a requisição, o evento `readyStateChange` vai ser chamado 4 vezes, em apenas 3 desses o `status` é 200, por isso ele executa as 3 vezes

Faça assim:

```
sendRequest = function() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("ok!");
            var response = this.responseText;
            console.log(response);
        }
    };
    http.open("GET", "test.py", true);
    http.send();
    console.log("called");
}
```